# Ошибка events.js:183 gulp при сжатии изображений

Tags: node.js, gulp

При сжатии изображений с помощью плагина Gulp не редко выпадает ошибка

[image: Ошибка при попытке оптимизировать изображения]

```
var gulp         = require('gulp'),     
    imagemin     = require('gulp-imagemin'),
        imageminJpegRecompress = require('imagemin-jpeg-recompress'),
        pngquant     = require('imagemin-pngquant');

gulp.task('images', function() {
    return gulp.src('img/**/*')
        .pipe(imagemin([
            imagemin.gifsicle({interlaced: true}),
            imagemin.jpegtran({progressive: true}),
            imageminJpegRecompress({
                loops: 5,
                min: 90,
                max: 95,
                quality:'medium'
        }),
            imagemin.svgo(),
            imagemin.optipng({optimizationLevel: 3}),
            pngquant({quality: '90-95', speed: 5})
    ],{
        verbose: true
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/img'));
});
```

Прошу помочь победить эту ошибку, уж очень нравится как сжимает изображения.

Comment: Какая версия `imagemin` используется?

Comment: @LEQADA "gulp": "^3.9.1", "gulp-imagemin": "^4.1.0", "imagemin-jpeg-recompress": "^5.1.0", "imagemin-pngquant": "^5.0.1"